# last row of GridBagLayout is smaller than the other

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I insert 12 Jpanel into 1 Jpanel GridBagLayout using 2 for loops but I can't have the last row same size as the other 2...
The 3 rows have plenty of space to fit into.

here's my code :

```
public Start() {
    initComponents();

    int i;
    int j;
    int n = 1;

    jPanel22.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (j=0;j<4;j++){

            TABLE_1 t = new TABLE_1(); // a custom JPanel
            t.getLabelNomTable().setText("TABLE "+ n);
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

            c.gridx = j;
            c.weightx = 1.0;
            c.gridy = i;
            c.weighty = 1.0;
           jPanel22.add(t, c);
           n++;
           }
     }
}
```

as you can see no matter au much space I make for the tables to fit on the left JPanel, netbeans gives the extra space to the two first rows and "cut" the last row.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you don't write all your code left justified, so don't expect us to read it that why. Properly format the code when you post it. Also post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We have no idea what your "TABLE_1" class is. So first get the formatting working with a JButton or other Swing component so learn the concept of how the GridBagLayout works. Also, if you want 12 equally size components, then use a `GridLayout`. Your question doesn't have enough information for us to give a complete answer.

Comment: Better formatting, but I didn't ask for an image. However, what I see is the panel is being truncated. Add the panel to a scroll pane. Without a proper :MCVE" I'm not going to spend any more time guessing. I don't see  a problem with the posted code. But as I already suggested. You should be using a GridLayout!

Comment: I think the problem came somehow from netbeans GUI bulder generated group layout of my main jframe. works fine now (using grid layout instead of gridbaglayout on my table panel as you advised), next time I'll try to post a proper "MCVE". thanks for your help!